# Change the color of the indentation

Tags: notepad++

I use a custom theme on Notepad++, using among other things a dark-colored text editor (see image). I find the color of the indentation dots (surrounded in red) too strong compared to the rest, I would like to know if there is no way to change the color of these dots,
I didn't find such a parameter in the software.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the color of the dots - 
Go to `Settings -> style Configurator` and select `Global Styles` in `Language` section, select `Indent guideline style` in `Style` section and change the `Foreground Color` as your wish.